# JAVA Initializing database environment

Tags: java

I am using berkeley database. You should open an environment (it is just some files in order to support locking etc) once and then using that environment open your database files...
The problem here is that Environment should be created once..

Having globals is considered bad idea...

What is the best practice to have it created one time only ?

Should i use Singleton pattern (enum implementation) or static , or another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the [Singleton anti-pattern](http://caines.ca/blog/programming/singletons-anti-pattern-or-worst-anti-pattern-ever/) nor static final is a really good idea. Your environment will be created once (I guess during startup of your system). This environment should be available to your system and your database manager can be passed to your DAOs from there.

Ideally, you'll want to use dependency injection to achieve this in the neatest way, such as that provided by the [Spring framework](http://www.springsource.org/).

Comment: But how to achieve that in this case??

Comment: It's a rather large topic to answer completely here. Have a look at Spring and articles such as: http://www.vogella.de/articles/SpringDependencyInjection/article.html and http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364527/Introduction-to-the-Spring-Framework

Comment: Okay... then more details are needed if you're looking for some code that will do the trick. Is this a webapp or does it run in any other runtime container? Does it start over a `main()` method?

Comment: It starts from a main method but i plan to include it to a web service in the future.

Comment: Depending on *which* web container you're going to use, you have different ways of injecting this dependency. I've *never* gone so basic as to use `main()`, but as I understand it, you're going to have to write your application container yourself to so it this way - which is probably not worth it. I would strongly suggest that you use a container that has already been tested, refined and documented rather than trying to do it yourself. You will otherwise distract yourself from writing a solution to your business problem.

Answer (score 1):

Singleton pattern is best.

Because even due to some reason if the environment or any object becomes null we can check in the **getInstance()** for null.

And if it is null we can create one. So every time there will be only one object.